# What to set for AllowOverride & Options

Tags: wordpress, apache, htaccess

What is normally used as settings for both production or development servers for settings `AllowOverride` & `Options`?

I will be needing to use .htaccess for WordPress so things like mod_rewrite etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AllowOverride All`

`Options FollowSymLinks`

Note: Options is actually optional.